# File download dialog does not work from a IE ModalDialog in IE9 when initiated from Flash

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a flash control which can download a file to a local machine. This flash control is used in a html page where the page displays in a IE modalDialog. When user clicks on a button on the flash control, user is prompted with file download dialog to specify the physical location and file name to save the file.

IE 9  - File download dialog does not appear and browser hangs.
IE 6, 7, 8 - No issue. File download dialog appears and able to save the file.

I have a sample test page in the link below to recreate the issue.
http://ie9isse.comuv.com/Parent.htm

I have seen similar problem reported in following links but don't see any resolution or workaround.

1. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieitprocurrentver/thread/ff363da9-a240-400d-8cc7-0872a3c100cd/
2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/iewebdevelopment/thread/8a1f0a0a-63af-4eeb-8007-681c7ca6c201
3. http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=89&t=8443&view=next
4. http://forums.adobe.com/message/4036831?tstart=0

My guess is, this is related with the change of how IE handles Model Dialog and scripting with Model Dialog. So If there are any official references to this behavior change, it would be helpful too.

Comment: I´ve got the same Problem and posted the issue in the Adobe Bugbase.
The bug seems to appear only on some Versions of IE9 32-Bit (not IE9 64-Bit) <https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3122718> Adobe set the Priority to "very high" a month ago, but there is no solution or workaround yet. Did you find any solution in the meantime?
I would appreciate any Answer, since it´s very important for our client. Greetings, Jörg

Comment: Hi Joerg, I have seen this issue in IE9 64bit (Windows 7). I checked the bug reported in Adobe Bugbase. Is the issue being fixed ? If so, what version of Flash Player ?

Answer (score 1):

Hold **`control`** button on your keyboard and click on the popup link, it works

Answer (score 0):

Probably it will work for you:

In Internet Explorer Go to 
Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Internet -> Custom level -> Automatic prompting for file downloads. Enable it as it is by default disabled in IE9.

Enable File download too, in case it is disabled.

Comment: Those settings are enabled.